# Multiple logins with 1 thread jmeter in multiple loops

Tags: loops, csv, authentication, jmeter

I have a scenario in which I need to test 1 user(thread) with 10 different users logins in 10 loops. For example in the first login attempt(loop) jmeter is picking username1 and executing whole test plan,in the second loop it will pick username 2 and excute the test plan.

Comment: I have added csv file with username and password and change the loop count to 10, is it a right way of doing it ?

Comment: Just play with the configuration and this is pretty much basic scenario. You will figure it out and that is effective learning. BTW, your approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. Create `credentials.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and place your username/password combinations there like

   ```
   username,password
   user1,pass1
   user2,pass2
   user3,pass3
   user4,pass4
   user5,pass5
   user6,pass6
   user7,pass7
   user8,pass8
   user9,pass9
   user10,pass10
   ```
4. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to your Test Plan and set it up like:

   [image]
5. Replace hard-coded (recorded?) username and password with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the CSV file, the syntax is `${username}` and `${password}` correspondingly

   [image]
6. You can add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in order to see request and response details and ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing.

   [image]

   As you can see JMeter Variables have been replaced with their respective values from the CSV file in the runtime.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T.